# Elasticsearch - configure for future indexes index.mapping.total_fields.limit

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have running `Elastic stack` - i get error on `systemctl status logstash.service -l` saying:

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [filebeat-2019.01.25] has been exceeded"}}}}
```

I know that i can configure this in `Kibana` here:
[image]

But i don't change this option here for `future` indicies, only for one specific.
I am wondering how can i change this option for all future indicies?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding new template (i will see in a while if this is an answer):

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9201/_template/filebeat" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{  
   "index_patterns":[  
      "filebeat*"
   ],
   "settings":{  
      "index":{  
         "codec":"best_compression",
         "mapping":{  
            "total_fields":{  
               "limit":"10000"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

And now i see it:

```
 sudo curl -X GET "localhost:9201/_template/filebeat*"


{"filebeat":{"order":0,"index_patterns":["filebeat*"],"settings":{"index":{"codec":"best_compression","mapping":{"total_fields":{"limit":"10000"}}}},"mappings":{},"aliases":{}}}
```

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _template/filebeat*`?

Comment: You mean something like `curl -X GET "localhost:9201/_template/filebeat*"` ??  Where `9201` is elasticSearch ? If so, i get `{}` as `response`. Filebeat is not installed on this machine for your information. The question is about `elasticsearch` that recieves logs from `filebeat` that is installed on another machine.

Comment: Still, an index template for Filebeat is supposedly installed in your ES.

Comment: @Val I have added template for tests - to see if this will fix my issue - see the question near `Edit` word.

Comment: Seems like you figured it out. That's the way to do it, all future `filebeat-*` indices will have those settings applied.